# Composition or engineering name for Soft iron core used in electromagnets

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I am trying to make an electromagnet and most online resources suggest soft iron core is used as the material. What is the composition or the engineering name for this soft iron?

Answer (score 0):

*mild steel* or *low-carbon steel* are commonly used for magnet cores. They consist almost entirely of iron.